# Failed to update data in Kendo grid, always creates data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, telerik-mvc

I want to make data CRUD inline in grid. Create method is successfully done. But when I try to do update, it always creates new data. When I try to do debugging, it always goes to the create method.

I'm using KendoUI, MVC4 in C#.

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace admission.Models
{
    public class JenisUjianModel
    {
        public JenisUjianModel() { }

        public int id_jenis_ujian { set; get; }
        public string jenis_ujian { set; get; }
        public DateTime tgl_ujian { set; get; }
        public string created { set; get; }
        public string createdBy { set; get; }
        public string modified { set; get; }
        public string modifiedBy { set; get; }
        public string flag { set; get; }
    }
    public class UjianJenisModel
    {
        pmbEntities entities = new pmbEntities();

        public IEnumerable<JenisUjianModel> Read()
        {
            return entities.Tbl_Jenis_Ujian.Select(jnis => new JenisUjianModel
            {
                id_jenis_ujian = jnis.id_jenis_ujian,
                jenis_ujian = jnis.jenis_ujian,
                tgl_ujian = jnis.Tgl_Ujian.Value
            }).OrderBy(u => u.id_jenis_ujian);
        }

        public void Create(JenisUjianModel jnis)
        {
            var entity = new Tbl_Jenis_Ujian();
            int last = entities.Tbl_Jenis_Ujian.Max(u => u.id_jenis_ujian);
            int coun = entities.Tbl_Jenis_Ujian.Count();
            if (coun == 0)
            {
                entity.id_jenis_ujian = 0;
            }
            else
                entity.id_jenis_ujian = last + 1;

            entity.jenis_ujian = jnis.jenis_ujian;
            entity.Tgl_Ujian = jnis.tgl_ujian;
            entity.created = DateTime.Now;
            entity.flag = "Y";

            entities.Tbl_Jenis_Ujian.Add(entity);
            entities.SaveChanges();

        }

        public void Update(JenisUjianModel jnis)
        {
            var entity = new Tbl_Jenis_Ujian();
            entity.id_jenis_ujian = jnis.id_jenis_ujian;
            entity.jenis_ujian = jnis.jenis_ujian;
            entity.Tgl_Ujian = jnis.tgl_ujian;
            entity.modified = DateTime.Now;
            entity.modifiedBy = jnis.modifiedBy;
            entity.created = DateTime.Parse(jnis.created);
            entity.createdBy = jnis.createdBy;
            entity.flag = jnis.flag;

            entities.Tbl_Jenis_Ujian.Attach(entity);
            entities.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            entities.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Destroy(JenisUjianModel jnis)
        {
            var entity = new Tbl_Jenis_Ujian();
            entity.id_jenis_ujian = jnis.id_jenis_ujian;
            entity.jenis_ujian = jnis.jenis_ujian;
            entity.Tgl_Ujian = jnis.tgl_ujian;
            entity.modified = DateTime.Parse(jnis.modified);
            entity.modifiedBy = jnis.modifiedBy;
            entity.created = DateTime.Parse(jnis.created);
            entity.createdBy = jnis.createdBy;
            entity.flag = "N";

            entities.Tbl_Jenis_Ujian.Attach(entity);
            entities.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            entities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using admission.Models;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace admission.Controllers
{
    public class UjianController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Ujian/

        UjianJenisModel uj = new UjianJenisModel();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult JenisUjian() { return View(); }
        
        public ActionResult jenisUjian_read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return Json(uj.Read().ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult jenisUjian_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, JenisUjianModel jnis)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                uj.Create(jnis);
            }

            return Json(new[] { jnis }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult jenisUjian_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, JenisUjianModel jnis)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                uj.Update(jnis);
            }

            return Json(new[] { jnis }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult jenisUjian_Delete([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, JenisUjianModel jnis)
        {
            if (jnis != null)
            {
                uj.Destroy(jnis);
            }

            return Json(new[] { jnis }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }

    }
}
```

View

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "JenisUjian";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_adminLayout.cshtml";
}

<div class="tables">
    <div class="table-responsive bs-example widget-shadow">
        <h4>Data Propinsi:</h4>
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<admission.Models.JenisUjianModel>()
    .Name("gridss")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.id_jenis_ujian).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(p => p.jenis_ujian).Title("Jenis Ujian");
        columns.Bound(p => p.tgl_ujian).Title("Tgl Ujian").Format("{0: dd MMM yyyy - HH:mm WIB}");
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(250);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:570px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(10)
        .Events(events => 
        { 
            events.Error("error_handler");
            events.RequestEnd("force_update");
        })
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.id_jenis_ujian))
        .Create(update1 => update1.Action("jenisUjian_Create", "Ujian"))
        .Update(update2=> update2.Action("jenisUjian_Update", "Ujian"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("jenisUjian_read", "Ujian"))
        .Destroy(update3 => update3.Action("jenisUjian_Delete", "Ujian"))
    )
)
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function error_handler(e) {    
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n";
            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function() {
                        message += this + "\n";
                    });
                }
            });        
            alert(message);
        }
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function force_update(e) {
        if (e.type === "create") {
            location.reload();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are finding that the create is always occuring this will be because of the `default` nature of the grid when generating the id.

When saving the item back to your system I am assuming it will auto-incrementing a  Primary Key somewhere. This `new` id needs to be assigned to the model that is presented back to the grid so it knows that an update action is to generated if further changes are done to this item.

So in the code section:

```
 uj.Create(jnis);
```

Change this so that it assigns the id back to model. Maybe something like this:

```
jnis.id_jenis_ujian = uj.Create(jnis);
```

or

```
jnis = uj.Create(jnis);
```

then change you Create signature to return either the int or the model back rather than have it as a void.

```
 public int Create(JenisUjianModel jnis)
 {
     ....Code removed for brevity
     int returnId = lastId + 1; 

     return returnId; 
 }
```

or

```
public JenisUjianModel Create(JenisUjianModel jnis)
     {
         ....Code removed for brevity
         jnis.id_jenis_ujian = lastId + 1; 

         return jnis; 
     }
```

Hopefully this should help you out.

Any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: didn't work. It still create new data. Failed to update

Comment: I didn't notice before but try disabling your `update` event `events.RequestEnd("force_update");` this may be interfering with the datasource so reloading a `cached` state

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Fiddler using the link below

> https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

As @David Shorthose mentioned the ID must be missed somewhere along the way.

Check the data you are sending to your action using Fiddler or debug your Grid data in Chrome developer tools(F12) using the code line below:

```
debugger;
$("#gridss").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
```

If you couldn't solve it by yourself then report back the data you have been gathered to make us able help you more insightful.